# Do I need to track macronutrients?

Tags: food

Do I need to track my cutting macronutrients, or can I just eat a good amount of protein and eat fewer carbs and fats? I'm doing this for fat loss and for maintaining muscle mass during cutting

Comment: "Eat[ing] a good amount of protein and eat[ing] fewer carbs" is tracking your macro's...